# .toggle() sometimes taking double click before working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple application, where I'd like to toggle between showing and hiding elements in a fieldset using jQuery's .toggle effect. The trouble is, occasionally I have to double-click the button that enables the toggle, to get it to work.

Any ideas on what's going on?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="LeftFrame">
    <div id="LeftTable"><strong>Left</div>
    </div>
    <div id="MainTable"><strong>Main
    <div>
        <br>
        <form><fieldset><legend><button id="buttonShowFields">Add Info</button></legend>
        <div id="InfoAddFields">
            ID: <input type="text"><br>
            Serial Number: <input type="text"><br>
            Location: <select id="inputLocation">
            <option>Location1</option>
            <option>Location2</option></select><br>
            Status: <select id="inputStatus">
            <option>Complete</option>
            <option>In Process</option></select><br>
        </div>
        </fieldset></form>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

... and javascript (test.js ref in html above):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Show options to add workorder
    // $("#WOAddFields").hide();
    $("#buttonShowFields").click(function(){
    $("#InfoAddFields").toggle();
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you say anything around when it takes a double click to toggle?  Is the animation still running?  Is it on first load only?  Is it after you've already toggled?  Is the first "missed" click close to the previous click and is thus registering as the second click of the previous click?  If you add a console.log in the click statement, do all the console.log events show up or are they missing too?

Comment: What are you doing to prevent the form from being submitted when the button is clicked?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me (after preventing the form submit and fixing some HTML). http://jsfiddle.net/3mtT8/

Comment: @EliGassert: seems to just require double clicking at random. Sometimes doubleclicking and single-clicking both do not work. Adding console.log before the toggle in the clicked block verifies that occasionally a single-click is not registered at all.

Comment: You are missing a closing `</select>` on your first select element.  Also are you doing anything to stop the form from being submitted?

Comment: @j08691: not sure what you mean - there is no action for submitting the form. Must something submit, just because I have a <form> tag?

Comment: The button element's default type is submit. Unless you're doing something to stop the button's default behavior, clicking it will submit the form.

Comment: @Ballbin: thank you, corrected the missing </select>. Still no change.

Comment: I see, so using the <form> tag is creating a situation where it tries to submit. Let me try without... yes, seems to work if <form> tags are taken out. That must be the problem! If anyone would care to elaborate in the form of an answer, I'll be happy to accept. Thank you everyone.

Comment: I don't know why it would work at all to be honest -- you should get the same result each time.

Comment: Change `click` to `mouseup`  do you then get all the console.log messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prevent the submit with [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) when you click the button

http://jsfiddle.net/3NPPP/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttonShowFields").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $("#InfoAddFields").toggle();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem when using plain javaScript to toggle an element with the following function:

```
function toggle(element){
  if (element.style.display !== "none")
    element.style.display = "none";
  else element.style.display = "block";
}
```

I noticed that when I added display:none to the CSS of the element I wanted to toggle, I needed to double click to first show the element. To fix this, I had to explicitly add **style="display:none"** to the HTML element tag.

Answer (score -1):

instead of this...

```
    <button id="buttonShowFields">Add Info</button>
```

use this...

```
    <input type="button" id="buttonShowFields" value="Add Info" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Please change event method to bind instead click.

```
$("#buttonShowFields").bind('click',function(){
    $("#InfoAddFields").toggle();
});
```